# transitioning to a new view after authentication is complete

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, authentication, asihttprequest

I currently have a simple iPad application built in xcode.

I have 2 `uitextfields` and a `uibutton`.

I have the application currently authenticating against a backend the username and password being input using `asihttprequest`.

Authentication is working as I see the success banner in the console.

I am trying have the current view controller transition to a new view but I am not totally sure how to do that.

Should I be declaring something within my `appdelegate` for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you probably need to declare something in your AppDelegate. This will be depending on your current layout, if you have a `UINavigationController` then what you will be doing is pushing a new ViewController into this `UINavigationController` to do this use:

```
//Do this to push your new view controller, in this case named authenticationViewController
[myNavController pushViewController:authenticatedViewController animated:YES];
```

If you do not understand about what I'm talking about you can read more about the UINavigationController Class in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I recommend you to read the introduction which contains an explanation about UIViewControllers and their transitions.

If you already have a navigation controller and a class, what you can do is to create a new subclass of UIViewController and then do something like:

```
NewViewController *viewController=[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil]; 
[[validationViewController navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

//Memory management
[viewController release];
```

Comment: The authentication is taking place in the default ViewController.m

Does the same apply? I was reading on one blog where this was actually being done in the AppDelegate.m instead but I would think it would work either way and then based on, for example a if logged in check the new view is displayed....

Comment: and actually looking up uinavigationcontrollers i would be pushing the new view into it after authentication was validated....i get it

Comment: Glad I was able to help, if so mark the question as answered. :D